# Render a sub-view in a parent when the sub-view fetched JSON data from service in Backbone

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, view, underscore.js

Am trying to solve this issue when rendering a sub view in a parent view.

The parent view is a static chunk of html that will be tabs for filtering the sub-view which is tabular data pulled from the server.

The issue is that the parent and sub-view render fine but the sub-view's collection has no data; but I can confirm that the service is returning data in the console.

This is my router:

```
define([
    'domLib',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'bootstrap',
    'view/logged-out',
    'view/leaderboard',
    'view/leaderboard-filter',  
    'view/leaderboard-overall',
    'view/login',
    'view/navigation'
], function($, _, Backbone, Bootstrap, LoggedOutView, LeaderboardView, LeaderboardFilter, OverallLeaderboardView, LoginView, NavigationView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'index',
            'leaderboard': 'leaderboard',
            'login': 'login'
        },
        index: function () {
            var loggedOutView = new LoggedOutView();
        },
        leaderboard: function(){
            var leaderboardFilter = new LeaderboardFilter();
            //var overallLeaderboardView = new OverallLeaderboardView();
        },
        login: function(){
            var loginView = new LoginView();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){

        var app_router = new AppRouter,
            leaderboardView = new LeaderboardView(),
            navigationView = new NavigationView();

        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

My parent view, called from the router:

```
define([
    'domLib',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'view/leaderboard-overall',
    'text!template/leaderboard-filter.html'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Router, OverallLeaderboardView, LeaderboardFilterTemplate) {

        var LeaderboardFilterView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: 'section[role="main"]',
            template: _.template(LeaderboardFilterTemplate),
            initialize: function(){
                this.innerView = new OverallLeaderboardView();
                this.render();
            },
            render: function(){
                this.$el.append(this.template());
                this.$el.append(this.innerView.render());
            }
        });

        return LeaderboardFilterView;
});
```

Then i would like to render a table view in the parent view template HTML:

```
define([
    'domLib',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'collection/leaderboard-overall',
    'text!template/leaderboard-overall.html'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Router, OverallLeaderboardCollection, OverallLeaderboardTemplate) {

        var OverallLeaderboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: 'section[role="main"]',
            template: _.template(OverallLeaderboardTemplate),
            initialize: function(){
                this.collection = new OverallLeaderboardCollection();
                this.collection.bind('reset', _.bind(this.render, this));
                this.collection.fetch();
            },
            render: function(){
                console.log('render overall leaderboard');
                this.$el.append(this.template({players: this.collection.toJSON()}));
            }
        });

        return OverallLeaderboardView;
});
```

Parent template (would like to render the sub-view in the .tab-pane):

```
<nav id="leaderboard-filter">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#all-time">All Time</a></li>
        <li><a href="#today">Today</a></li>
        <li><a href="#week">This Week</a></li>
        <li><a href="#month">This Month</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane">
            <!-- Render leaderboard -->
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Sub-view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>                             
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Games Completed</th>
            <th>High Score</th>
            <th>Percent Correct</th>
            <th>Avg Answer Time</th>
            <th>Cumulative Score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <!-- Logged in user details here -->
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <% _.each(players, function(player, index){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
                <td><a href="/hyc-web/"><%= _.escape(player.user) %></a></td>
                <td><%= player.games_completed %></td>
                <td><%= player.high_score %></td>
                <td><%= player.percent_correct %></td>
                <td><%= player.avg_answer_time %></td>
                <td><%= player.cumulative_score %></td>
            </tr>           
        <% }); %>                                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Both render in order but the sub-view does not render any data just table headers.

Can;t figure out how to get this working?

Comment: Backbone version? Also, if you could post the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See RullDawg's answer for part of your problem.
The other part is that you're probably missed a few things while upgrading to [Backbone 1.0](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog).

"*Renamed Collection's "update" to set, for parallelism with the similar model.set(), and contrast with reset. It's now the default updating mechanism after a fetch. If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass {reset: true}.*"

So basically, the only time you render your subview is when you render it in the parent view (I don't know why you're doing it btw). You listen to the `reset` event while it's never triggered. Change it to `this.collection.fetch({reset: true});` and be careful of what you're appending to the DOM and it should work.

If you don't want to use the `reset` flag, you could listen to the more generic `sync` event.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the child's el when appending.

From

```
this.$el.append(this.innerView.render());
```

To

```
this.$el.append(this.innerView.render().el);
```

Answer (score 1):

What i understand is that it is not rendering data while collection has the data at backend.
Now there is a flaw in your code.
fetch() is Async call.
So to make sure that your data is available while rendering view is to writes success handler.
and move your logic of fetch to render() function
for example
if I see your fetch code in OverAllLeatherBoardView

```
initialize: function(){
            this.collection = new OverallLeaderboardCollection();
            this.collection.bind('reset', _.bind(this.render, this));
            //this.collection.fetch(); move it to render function
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log('render overall leaderboard');
            this.collection.fetch({success: $.proxy(myDelegate, this)})
            //this.$el.append(this.template({players: this.collection.toJSON()})); move it to delegate
        },
        //here you go
        mDelegate:function(model, response, options){
          this.$el.append(this.template({players: model.toJSON()}));
        }
```

Comment: You obviously missed the fact that he added a listener: `this.collection.bind('reset', _.bind(this.render, this));`. There's no need to provide a success callback.